# Google plus does not show the thumbnail when I share my website's link

Tags: facebook, html, google-plus

I had faced the same problem earlier on Facebook too, but using the following tag solved the problem:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="link to image" />
```

The dimensions of the image in the "link to image" are 200px x 200px, which is same as what is required by Facebook.

Now when I share the same link on Google Plus, there isn't any thumbnail. Why is that?

Comment: Go check your URL here: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: It doesn't show the thumbnail in the preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Google can read the OpenGraph protocol, it doesn't handle it very well. The suggested way to do this is to add schema.org microdata, so the body of your HTML might be marked up something like:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
```

(note the new itemscope and itemtype parameters) and the image you want to use gets an itemprop parameter such as

```
<img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
```

See https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ for details and for links to some tools to help you with this as well. As CBroe noted, https://google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets can help you debug the page.

Comment: Okay! Got it! The links were really helpful.